# who know that the CGAL simplication use which paper?

Tags: cgal

I have developed a new method about mesh simplification on CGAL. But I don`t know which paper do the CGAL used? could you help me ?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? It references quite a few publications. The list may not be complete, but that's already a good basis...

Answer (score 0):

In the [User Manual](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_simplification/index.html#Chapter_Triangulated_Surface_Mesh_Simplification) of the mesh simplification package you find the sentence:

> "The cost-driven method implemented in this package is mainly based on [4], [5], with contributions from [3], [2] and [1 ]."

so, please follow the links.

Comment: Thank you so much!